# Reading an input from the ModelSim transcript window

Tags: system, verilog

Is reading an input from ModelSim transcript window possible? If yes, how to read the inputs?

Comment: What do you mean by read an input? A transcript window prints out logs. There are no inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read input from the user, or from a file, use the Verilog Programming Language Interface (PLI) to connect your verilog to the C or C++ language; and there you can use system calls like read and fgetc to get data from a file, or from the user.

See your verilog simulator's manual, or a do a web search for ModelSim PLI for help to using the Verilog PLI.